# Separate Admin and Front in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, admin, frontend

What is the best way to separate admin and front-end for a website in codeigniter where as I was to use all libraries, models, helpers etc. in common, but only controllers and Views will be separate.

I want a more proper way, up for performance, simplicity, and sharing models and libraries etc.

Answer (score 16):

I highly suggest reading the methods outlined in this article by CI dev Phil Sturgeon:

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter

My advice: Use modules for organizing your project.

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home

Create a [base controller](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html) for the front and/or backend. Something like this:

```
// core/MY_Controller.php
/**
 * Base Controller
 * 
 */ 
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
                      // or MX_Controller if you use HMVC, linked above
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Load shared resources here or in autoload.php
    }
}

/**
 * Back end Controller
 * 
 */ 
class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Check login, load back end dependencies
    }
}

/**
 * Default Front-end Controller
 * 
 */ 
class Public_Controller extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Load any front-end only dependencies
    }
}
```

Back end controllers will `extend Admin_Controller`, and front end controllers will `extend Public_Controller`. The front end base controller is not really necessary, but there as an example, and can be useful. You can extend `MY_Controller` instead if you want.

Use [URI routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) where needed, and create separate controllers for your front end and back end. All helpers, classes, models etc. can be shared if both the front and back end controllers live in the same application.

Comment: I find this approach very usefull, but I have a question though cause I don't get it. Why do you create a MY_Controller? is it necessary?? what if Admin_Controller and Public_Controller extend the CI_Controller instead? would this be correct too??

Comment: Newest link: https://phil.tech/2009/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter/

Answer (score 12):

I use a very simple approach: file folders. Check out the CI User Guide section, [Organizing Your Controllers into Sub-folders](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#subfolders).

I have my public-facing website built as any other would be built with CodeIgniter.  Then I have two additional folders, `controllers/admin` and `views/admin`.

The admin controllers are accessed via *http://[hostname]/admin/controller*, and behave just as any other controller except they have specific authentication checks.  Likewise, the views are simply called with the folder name included: `$this->load->view('admin/theview');`.

I haven't found a reason to do anything more complicated than that.

Comment: Hey you're "Organizing Your Controllers into Sub-folders." link is not working could you please give me updated one.

Comment: This is the latest link http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/controllers.html#subfolders

Answer (score 3):

You all can find complete solution over here, https://github.com/bhuban/modular

Module separation for admin and front-end using HMVC and template separation using template libraries

I am using two third party libraries, you can find it in zip file.

1. HMVC for modular developed by wiredesignz
2. Template engine for templating by Phil Sturgeon

Just unzip it into your webserver root directory and run

```
localhost/modular for front-end
```

and

```
localhost/modular/admin for back-end
```

`application/back-modules`, it is for the back-end modules

`application/front-modules`, it is for the front-end modules

similarly
`templates/admin` for the back-end templates
`templates/front` for the front-end templates

`themes/admin` for the back-end themes
`themes/front` for the front-end themes

Nothing hacked in original code just configured using config.php and index.php

Comment: This is exactelly that i searched! but when i try to access it, i've an error : Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid. Have you an idea to solve it ? Thanks

Comment: could you please answer above question, need your help
  "Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid."