# codeigniter separating frontend and backend

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I've read these pages regarding this:

> http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter
>
> [Separate Admin and Front in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511425/seperate-admin-and-front-in-codeigniter) (look at answer by Madmartigan)

their both good approaches but I'm not sure if that is what I'm looking for.

I want to separate the front-end from the back-end I was thinking of a layout like this: (view image)
I  am about to convert large web applications to CI and to keep everything as organized as possible i figured this folder layout would be the best approach but since im a newbie to CI would you consider this layout? I have attempted this layout already as a test and I would run into problems since the directory is named back-end or front-end so when I would type say:

```
http://example.com/backend/mycontroller/mymethod I would reach a 404 page.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking into this last week, for a small project I was setting up (in the end I went with Kohana 2.3.4, but never mind :P)

The best file system I came up with for CodeIgniter is this:

```
/ application
/ - /admin
/ - - /config
/ - - /controllers
/ - - /models
/ - - /views
/ - /public
/ - - /config
/ - - /controllers
/ - - /models
/ - - /views
/ core
/ - /all the core stuff
/ public_html
/ - /admin
/ - - index.php
/ - index.php
```

The problem here is there's no code-sharing going on between the two, so you can't re-use any stuff - if you're OK with that (probably not good for a large application), this should probably do what you want.

If switching to Kohana is an option, give me a shout and I'll post my structure for that - it's similar to this, but has an extra level where I the front-end and back-end can share code, while still using their specific code as a priority. It's much nicer for anything bigger than a small application :)

Comment: i like your layout more than mine. did you make public_html the root for the domain?

Comment: Yep, and the `index.php` files just point all the roots to `../` followed by whatever they need to be (or `../../` for the admin one). Keeps the application files outside of the webroot

Comment: btw, rather than doing ../ try something like this , this is my example that i use define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', str_replace('/public', '', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));

Comment: No point, you only put it in the config paths to tell the bootstrap where to look for your application. Once it knows that, the framework adjusts the paths for you