# Front-end and admin panel setup in single CodeIgniter 3 installation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am starting a new application in which I want to implement CodeIgnitor 3. I need a front-end website and admin panel. But want to use same CI installation, instead of having two CI instances.

I want to run url like this, `http://example.com/` and admin panel will live at `http://example.com/adm/`.

How to setup it in CodeIgniter 3? Please advise?

Comment: It was asked in 2011, things have changed in CI since then. Someone might know some way. Also that question sis not marked as answer yet.

Comment: @Prashant the second answer is still very applicable is CI3, and the way we currently implement this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7529723/3629438