# Multiple CodeIgniter application folder

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am going to create a web page that has two parts - main page and admin page. I like to do it in CodeIgniter. So I want two separate application folder for main page and admin page in one CodeIgniter. How can I create and configure two application folders and how to link both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separate Admin and Front in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511425/separate-admin-and-front-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I like to do is the following:

Firstly, duplicate the `index.php` located under the root folder.
I would rename it to `admin.php`.

Open the `admin.php`, locate the following line:

```
$application_folder = 'application';
```

Change to:

```
$application_folder = 'application/admin';
```

Do the same on the `index.php` but change the line to:

```
$application_folder = 'application/front';
```

Go into the Application folder and create two folders:

> application/admin/
>
> application/front/

Copy all the content that is under application for both admin/ and front/ and then delete those folders from the application root folder.

It should look like that:

[image: it should look like that]

I also recommend you to do the same for assets, having both folders to separate the content:

> assets/admin
>
> assets/front

Comment: And what about htaccess,i cant access admin without using admin.php

Comment: As it's an admin you shouldn't need it. In case you really want to do that just follow the documentation on https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html

Comment: Thank you so much:)