# CodeIgniter - How to create both front-end and back-end and share common functions?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter, and I need to create an admin side (back-end) and a client side (front-end). I followed [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48742951/multiple-codeigniter-application-folder).

[image]

Controllers, models folders are in both admin folder and front folder, but I wonder if I do it in this way, how am I going to share commonly used functions in models?

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511425/separate-admin-and-front-in-codeigniter

Comment: whats the reason to split this in two applications ? imho there is no real need for that...